# How do I route websocket requests to SailsJS without breaking the built in abstraction

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, sails.js

I am new to SailsJS and I am building an API for a iOS application. As per the SailsJS documentation it provides and abstraction for the Socket IO requests and routes it to my controllers. 
For example if I emit some data to `/user/create` it will automatically call the `UserController -> create` function. From what I understood I need to use the `sails.io.js` file on client side and emit using `Socket.get` and `Socket.post`.

As I am using this as an API for an iOS where iOS app is the client, how do I emit data to the server while using the routing feature in Sails JS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [source code for sails.io.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-frontend/blob/master/templates/assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js), you'll see it's just a bunch of helper methods thinly wrapping the Socket.io client.  The upshot is, you can still use Sails' wonderful routing-over-sockets mechanism using regular `socket.emit` calls.  Just use the HTTP method as the event name, and send the URL and data as the payload.  For example:

```
socket.emit('get', {url: 'http://example.com/foo'}, cb);
socket.emit('post', {url: 'http://example.com/bar', data: {name: 'joe'}}, cb);
```

where `cb` is a callback that will receive the result of the call as its sole argument.

Upcoming versions of Sails will support a second argument to the callback which contains more data about the response, like a status code and errors.

Comment: This is no longer possible with Sails 1.2.3